# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'dict' and 'str'

Tags: python

student scores:

```
student_scores = {
  "Harry": 81,
  "Ron": 78,
  "Hermione": 99, 
  "Draco": 74,
  "Neville": 62,
}
```

My goal is to print a dictionary with the students and the scores.

E.g. '{'Harry': 'Exceeds Expectations', 'Ron': 'Acceptable', 'Hermione': 'Outstanding', 'Draco': 'Acceptable', 'Neville': 'Fail'}'

Here is the scoring criteria:

Scores 91 - 100: Grade = "Outstanding"

Scores 81 - 90: Grade = "Exceeds Expectations"

Scores 71 - 80: Grade = "Acceptable"

Scores 70 or lower: Grade = "Fail"

Here is my code:

```
student_scores = {
  "Harry": 81,
  "Ron": 78,
  "Hermione": 99, 
  "Draco": 74,
  "Neville": 62,

student_grades = {}

for key in student_scores:
    if student_scores[key] >= 91:
        student_scores[key] = "Outstanding"
    elif student_scores[key] >= 81:
        student_scores[key] = "Exceeds Expectations"
    elif student_scores[key] >= 71:
        student_scores[key] = "Acceptable"
    elif student_scores[key] <= 70:
        student_scores[key] = "Fail"
    student_grades += key
    student_grades[key] += student_scores[key]

print(student_grades)
```

When I tried to run my code, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 23, in <module>
    student_grades += key
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'dict' and 'str'
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: So you already change the stored integer to a string with the if - else if statements, you don't need to add the key back into the dictionary for it to be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the exception message points out, the line `student_grades += key` isn't doing anything that makes sense. `student_grades` is an (initially empty) dictionary, and `key` is a string with the name of a student in it. You can't add those things together. I'm not even sure what you intended it to do, so I can't exactly tell you what to do differently to achieve your objective.

What I do see is that you're modifying the dictionary with the input scores in place in the `if`/`elif` blocks. Perhaps you don't want to be doing that? If you changed all the assignment statements to use `student_grades` instead of `student_scores` (while leaving the references to `students_scores` in the `if` and `elif` conditions), you'd probably get what you wanted, without any extra steps:

```
for key in student_scores:
    if student_scores[key] >= 91:
        student_grades[key] = "Outstanding"   # change to student_grades here
    elif student_scores[key] >= 81:
        student_grades[key] = "Exceeds Expectations"  # and here
    elif student_scores[key] >= 71:
        student_grades[key] = "Acceptable"            # and here
    elif student_scores[key] <= 70:
        student_grades[key] = "Fail"                  # here too
```

As a bonus, you won't have clobbered the `student_scores` dict after this loop, so you can still refer back to it if necessary.

Comment: " I'm not even sure what you intended it to do" I find the thinking not particularly opaque, albeit quite wrong: they want to add something to the dictionary, and when they think "add", they think `+`.